# MySQL multiple values on own columns

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like so;

```
id1     id2
1       1
2       1
1       2
3       2
1       3
4       3
1       4
5       4
```

I'd like to select it in a way that I'd get rows `GROUP`ed by `id2`, but still preserving both values of `id1` for the corresponding rows in the table.

So I'd get a result set like so;

```
id1     id1     id2
1       2       1
1       3       2
1       4       3
1       5       4
```

I've never been even half good in advanced database queries -- how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Don't use GROUP, use ORDER BY id2.

Comment: For every different value of `id2`, do only 2 values of `id1` exist in the table? What if there are more? Or less (just one)?

Comment: There are always exactly and precisely two values in `id1` for every `id2` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have exactly 2 rows (with 2 values for `id1`) for every different value of `id2`, you can use this:

```
SELECT MIN(id1) AS id1_a
     , MAX(id1) AS id1_b
     , id2
FROM tableX
GROUP BY id2 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

```
SELECT id2, GROUP_CONCAT(id1) FROM your_table
GROUP BY id2
```

This way you have, for each id2 value, a column with all id1 values comma separated.
Take a look at [GROUP_CONCAT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the perfect solution but in your case, it should work. This is a trick I used.

select id1, (sum(id1) - id1 ) as nID1, id2 from table_name group by id2

Hope it works.
Ujjwal